# Estructura de base de datos firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Que tal solicito sugerencias, tengo un proyecto para una escuela, queremos hacerlo con firestore, necesitamos que en la base de datos se almacenen los años con los pagos mensuales de cada alumno, no se cual es la mejor manera de estructurar la base de datos para que podamos reportearlos tipo un kardex por año, donde salga todo un año con los nombres de los alumnos y si pagaron o no los distintos meses ¿alguien que me de alguna sugerencia de como estructurar los datos?

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
    pagos: [
      {
        idPago: 'pago1',
        fechaPago: '01/01/2020',
        cantidad: 400,
        idAlumno: 'alumno2',
        otrosCampos: ''
      },
      {
        idPago: 'pago2',
        fecha: '01/05/2020',
        cantidad: 200,
        idAlumno: 'alumno1',
        otrosCampos: ''
      }
    ],
    alumnos: [
      {
        idAlumno: 'alumno1',
        nombre: 'nombre',
        appellido: 'apellido',
        otrosCampos: ''
      },
      {
        idAlumno: 'alumno2',
        nombre: 'nombre',
        appellido: 'apellido',
        otrosCampos: ''
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

No se si te pueda servir esta informacion, pero es un json estructurado con la información que puedes solicitar de cada alumno y el pago es una entidad aparte, que va conectada con los ids de los alumnos, para saber quien pago y en que fecha, al momento de mostrar los datos al cliente, puedes filtrar los pagos por el idAlumno y por la fecha de pago.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias @hectorromerodev por la sugerencia, eso debe funcionar pero lo que quiero es facilitarme la vida para que pueda en una sola consulta traerme todos los alumnos con todos sus meses del año para fácilmente renderizarlos en una tabla en angular, esto pensando en tener un documento que tenga el nombre del alumno, algo como lo que sigue ¿crees que funcione o sea lo adecuado?:

```
pagos2020: [
  {
    idAlumno: 'alumno1',
    nombre: 'nombre',
    enero: 'pagado',
    febrero: 'pagado'
    marzo: ''
... resto de meses
  },
  {
    nombre: 'nombre',
    enero: 'pagado',
    febrero: 'pagado'
    marzo: ''
... resto de meses
  }
]
```

pagos2021: [
{
idAlumno: 'alumno1',
nombre: 'nombre',
enero: 'pagado',
febrero: 'pagado'
marzo: ''
... resto de meses
},
{
nombre: 'nombre',
enero: 'pagado',
febrero: 'pagado'
marzo: ''
... resto de meses
}
]